# How do I perform a GROUP BY on an aliased column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax

I'm trying to perform a *group by* action on an aliased column (example below) but can't determine the proper syntax.

```
SELECT       LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS 'FullName'
FROM         customers
GROUP BY     'FullName'
```

What is the correct syntax?

Extending the question further (I had not expected the answers I had received) would the solution still apply for a CASEed aliased column?

```
SELECT       
    CASE
        WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN FirstName
        WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL THEN LastName + ', ' + FirstName
    END AS 'FullName'
FROM         customers
GROUP BY     
    LastName, FirstName
```

And the answer is yes it does still apply.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You pass the expression you want to group by rather than the alias

```
SELECT       LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS 'FullName'
FROM         customers
GROUP BY      LastName + ', ' + FirstName
```

Comment: no need to put the ', ' in GROUP BY.  the grouping can be indicated with or without the ', ', you can even avoid the typo (e.g. ','), so no invalid query error could arise

Comment: Are you referring to my suggestion, or to removing the + ', ' + from the group by expression?

Comment: just remove the ', ' in group by clause.  this works: select lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname
from person
group by lastname, firstname

Comment: You should leave it in, at least to differentiate between 'x, yz' and 'xy, z' which would roll up to the same string without the comma.

Comment: @NXC: "GROUP BY LastName + FirstName" can fall into the trap you explain, but you can't group by that and have "LastName + ', ' + FirstName" in the SELECT.  Using "GROUP BY LastName, FirstName", however, would be fine.  (See my comment on the poster's question.)

Comment: +1 Dems **GROUP BY Lastname, Firstname** would be just fine.  Explanation here http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/some-wrong-voted-answer-on.html

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells After six years, I now realized where the confusion from my suggestion to remove the ', ' come from, when I said "just remove the ', ' in group by clause", what I mean is just remove the concatenation from the GROUP BY, and then just group things by their entity, which is lastname and firstname, and not removing the concatenation from SELECT; in fact I [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497241/how-do-i-perform-a-group-by-on-an-aliased-column-in-ms-sql-server/497263#comment313078_497251) in second sentence what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: This SHOULD NOT be accepted answer cause it doesn't answer the question.What if in my SELECT i have IFF statement and then cast it? then order by column is not good, cause aliased column have different values and so on.

Answer (score 64):

This is what I do.

```
SELECT FullName
FROM
(
  SELECT LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS FullName
  FROM customers
) as sub
GROUP BY FullName
```

---

This technique applies in a straightforward way to your "edit" scenario:

```
SELECT FullName
FROM
(
  SELECT
     CASE
       WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN FirstName
       WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL THEN LastName + ', ' + FirstName
     END AS FullName
  FROM customers
) as sub
GROUP BY FullName
```

Comment: Ah! From! I should have guessed. I was just trying to nest a Select inside a Select. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately you can't reference your alias in the GROUP BY statement, you'll have to write the logic again, amazing as that seems.

```
SELECT       LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS 'FullName'
FROM         customers
GROUP BY     LastName + ', ' + FirstName
```

Alternately you could put the select into a subselect or common table expression, after which you could group on the column name (no longer an alias.)

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, this is not possible with MS SQL Server (possible though with PostgreSQL):

```
select lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname
from person
group by fullname
```

Otherwise just use this:

```
select x.fullname
from 
(
    select lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname
    from person
) as x
group by x.fullname
```

Or this:

```
select lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname
from person
group by lastname, firstname  -- no need to put the ', '
```

The above query is faster, groups the fields first, then **compute** those fields.

The following query is slower (it tries to **compute** first the select expression, then it groups the records based on that computation).

```
select lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname
from person
group by lastname + ', ' + firstname
```

Comment: FWIW you can also use column aliases in GROUP BY in MySQL.  But strictly, it isn't supported by the SQL standard.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is:

```
SELECT       LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS 'FullName'
FROM         customers
GROUP BY     LastName + ', ' + FirstName
```

Oracle has a similar limitation, which is annoying.  I'm curious if there exists a better solution.

To answer the second half of the question, this limitation applies to more complex expressions such as your case statement as well.  The best suggestion I've seen it to use a sub-select to name the complex expression.

Comment: no need to put the ', ' in GROUP BY. the grouping can be indicated with or without the ', ', you can even avoid the typo (e.g. ','), so no invalid query error could arise

Comment: True.  But I find the above a touch more clear.  Your sub-select solution is even clearer, obviously.  ;-)

Comment: You need the comma to avoid the edge case 'ab, c' vs 'a,bc'.  They would roll up the same without the comma.

Comment: @EricJ. What I mean on my first comment is remove the concatenation entirely from GROUP BY, not suggesting to merely remove the string ', ' and then keep the concatenation. There's no edge case even when you remove the concatenation entirely on GROUP BY. My first comment (merely remove the string ', ') on your answer is confusing, it looks like I'm suggesting to keep the concatenation on GROUP BY and just remove the string ', ',  but that's not what I mean, sorry for that confusion.  Slow performance of GROUP BY concatenation: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/some-wrong-voted-answer-on.html

Comment: Same answer as accepted answer, but this one has useful comments. Maybe add that in your answer to make your answer distinctive from the accepted one? and help people like me along when we are forced to work with legacy stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Given your edited problem description, I'd suggest using `COALESCE()` instead of that unwieldy `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT FullName
FROM (
  SELECT COALESCE(LastName+', '+FirstName, FirstName) AS FullName
  FROM customers
) c
GROUP BY FullName;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to create an alias and use it in the `GROUP BY` clause, like so:

```
SELECT       FullName
FROM         Customers
CROSS APPLY  (SELECT LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS FullName) Alias
GROUP BY     FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT       
    CASE
        WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN FirstName
        WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL THEN LastName + ', ' + FirstName
    END AS 'FullName'
FROM
    customers
GROUP BY     
    LastName,
    FirstName
```

This works because the formula you use (the CASE statement) can never give the same answer for two different inputs.

This is not the case if you used something like:

```
LEFT(FirstName, 1) + ' ' + LastName
```

In such a case "James Taylor" and "John Taylor" would both result in "J Taylor".

If you wanted your output to have "J Taylor" twice (one for each person):

```
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName
```

If, however, you wanted just one row of "J Taylor" you'd want:

```
GROUP BY LastName, LEFT(FirstName, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the old [FoxPro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro) (I haven't used it since version 2.5), you could write something like this:

```
SELECT       LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS 'FullName', Birthday, Title
FROM         customers
GROUP BY     1,3,2
```

I really liked that syntax. Why isn't it implemented anywhere else? It's a nice shortcut, but I assume it causes other problems?

Comment: This is still possible but is generally frowned upon.  Developers end up adding a new column to the middle of your column list and then unexpectedly changing the grouping criteria.  It's one of those things that works but is considered poor form, like putting select * from in your queries.

Comment: @ShaneDelmore I know this is an ancient thread, but which engines support this syntax today? What is the term for this use? Can you use such non-aliases in other clauses (e.g. `WHERE`/`HAVING`)? If so, how does the engine know how to distinguish field #2 from the integer 2 (e.g. `WHERE 2 is not NULL` / `HAVING 2 = 1`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the mess of the case statement being in your query twice, you may want to place it in a User-Defined-Function.

Sorry, but SQL Server would not render the dataset before the Group By clause so the column alias is not available. You could use it in the Order By.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN FirstName         
     WHEN LastName IS NOT NULL THEN LastName + ', ' + FirstName     
END AS 'FullName' 
FROM  customers GROUP BY 1`
```

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/497268/249353 to see why this way of grouping is not preferable.

Comment: Asked 3 years ago, accepted answer with 14 upvotes 3 years ago too.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds themselves with the following problem (grouping by ensuring zero and null values are treated as equals)...

```
SELECT AccountNumber, Amount AS MyAlias
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY AccountNumber, ISNULL(Amount, 0)
```

*(I.e. SQL Server complains that you haven't included the field Amount in your Group By or aggregate function)*

...remember to place the exact same function in your SELECT...

```
SELECT AccountNumber, ISNULL(Amount, 0) AS MyAlias
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY AccountNumber, ISNULL(Amount, 0)
```