# GROUP BY shows the same group more than once when using CASE

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, case

I'm having an issue with a `CASE` Statement in T-SQL

Here is the query:

```
Select 
 CASE WHEN cri.ChartRetrievalMethodID IS NULL THEN wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
 ELSE cri.ChartRetrievalMethodID END as Type,
 count(distinct c.chartid) TotalCharts 
From Sites s LEFT JOIN Charts c ON s.SiteID=c.SiteID 
LEFT JOIN ChartRetrievalInformation cri ON c.ChartID=cri.ChartID 
LEFT JOIN WFSiteEvents wfse ON wfse.SiteID=s.siteid 
LEFT JOIN WFSiteEventTypes wfset ON wfset.EventTypeID=wfse.EventTypeID 
LEFT JOIN WFSiteEventGroups wfseg ON wfset.SiteEventGroupID=wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
Where 
 wfse.EventStatusID in (1,2)
 and s.ProjectID=110
group by 
 cri.ChartRetrievalMethodID, wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
```

I'm getting a lot of multiple rows instead of them combining into one - example:

```
+------+--------------+
| Type | Total Charts |
+------+--------------+
| 3    | 28           |
| 3    | 3            |
+------+--------------+
```

Ideally I would like these two rows mashed together to be just one:

```
+------+--------------+
| Type | Total Charts |
+------+--------------+
| 3    | 31           |
+------+--------------+
```

I'm sure there is nothing I'm writing incorrectly but I can't seem to see what it is.

Comment: You can group by the entire case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the fields `cri.ChartRetrievalMethodID, wfseg.SiteEventGroupID` in the column list for your select statement, it will become clear to you why these are shown in multiple rows with that grouping.

What you want to do is group by the value you're calling `Type`. In another DBMS this would be as simple as `GROUP BY Type`, but [in SQL Server you must repeat the full expression in the `GROUP BY` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/497241/2359271).