# Invalid column name when using count distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm stumped... When I added the count distinct and group by statements to my query I get an error telling me that CallTime and Ticketday are invalid column names. How can I accomplish this without having to write this data to a table first and then query it?

```
select datename(weekday, calllog.RecvdDate) as Ticketday,
CASE WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '00:00:00' and '01:00:00' THEN '00:00 to 01:00' 
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '01:00:00' and '02:00:00' THEN '01:00 to 02:00' 
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '02:00:00' and '03:00:00' THEN '02:00 to 03:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '03:00:00' and '04:00:00' THEN '03:00 to 04:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '04:00:00' and '05:00:00' THEN '04:00 to 05:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '05:00:00' and '06:00:00' THEN '05:00 to 06:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00' THEN '06:00 to 07:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '07:00:00' and '08:00:00' THEN '07:00 to 08:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '08:00:00' and '09:00:00' THEN '08:00 to 09:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00' THEN '09:00 to 10:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00' THEN '10:00 to 11:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '11:00:00' and '12:00:00' THEN '11:00 to 12:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '12:00:00' and '13:00:00' THEN '12:00 to 13:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '13:00:00' and '14:00:00' THEN '13:00 to 14:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '14:00:00' and '15:00:00' THEN '14:00 to 15:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '15:00:00' and '16:00:00' THEN '15:00 to 16:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '16:00:00' and '17:00:00' THEN '16:00 to 17:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '17:00:00' and '18:00:00' THEN '17:00 to 18:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '18:00:00' and '19:00:00' THEN '18:00 to 19:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '19:00:00' and '20:00:00' THEN '19:00 to 20:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '20:00:00' and '21:00:00' THEN '20:00 to 21:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '21:00:00' and '22:00:00' THEN '21:00 to 22:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '22:00:00' and '23:00:00' THEN '22:00 to 23:00'
    WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '23:00:00' and '23:59:59' THEN '23:00 to 00:00'
    END as CallTime, count(distinct(CallTime)) as CallCount
from SERVER.xxxx.dbo.view_calllog calllog
where calllog.RecvdDate > '2015-01-01'
and calllog.NameRecvdBy = 'IVR User Account'
and calllog.CallDesc LIKE '%string%'
group by Ticketday, CallTime
order by Ticketday, CallTime
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497241/how-do-i-perform-a-group-by-on-an-aliased-column-in-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the query is parsed the alias `CallTime` hasn't been defined when you try to use it in the select statement.

One solution would be to wrap your query in a common table expression (or use it as a derived table) like this:

```
;WITH cte (Ticketday, CallTime) AS (
    SELECT 
       DATENAME(weekday, calllog.RecvdDate) AS Ticketday,
       CASE 
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '01:00:00' THEN '00:00 to 01:00' 
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '02:00:00' THEN '01:00 to 02:00' 
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '02:00:00' AND '03:00:00' THEN '02:00 to 03:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '03:00:00' AND '04:00:00' THEN '03:00 to 04:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '05:00:00' THEN '04:00 to 05:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '06:00:00' THEN '05:00 to 06:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '07:00:00' THEN '06:00 to 07:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '08:00:00' THEN '07:00 to 08:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '09:00:00' THEN '08:00 to 09:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '10:00:00' THEN '09:00 to 10:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '11:00:00' THEN '10:00 to 11:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '11:00:00' AND '12:00:00' THEN '11:00 to 12:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '13:00:00' THEN '12:00 to 13:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '14:00:00' THEN '13:00 to 14:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '15:00:00' THEN '14:00 to 15:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '16:00:00' THEN '15:00 to 16:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '16:00:00' AND '17:00:00' THEN '16:00 to 17:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '18:00:00' THEN '17:00 to 18:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '19:00:00' THEN '18:00 to 19:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '20:00:00' THEN '19:00 to 20:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '21:00:00' THEN '20:00 to 21:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '21:00:00' AND '22:00:00' THEN '21:00 to 22:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:00:00' THEN '22:00 to 23:00'
          WHEN calllog.RecvdTime BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '23:59:59' THEN '23:00 to 00:00'
       END AS CallTime
    FROM SERVER.xxxx.dbo.view_calllog calllog
    WHERE calllog.RecvdDate > '2015-01-01'
    AND calllog.NameRecvdBy = 'IVR User Account'
    AND calllog.CallDesc LIKE '%string%'
)
SELECT Ticketday, COUNT(DISTINCT CallTime) AS CallCount 
FROM cte
GROUP BY Ticketday, CallTime
ORDER BY Ticketday, CallTime
```

Also, `distinct` is not a function. The proper syntax is `count(distinct CallTime)`.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly! Turns out I just needed the count and not the count distinct, but thanks for the clarification on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put column aliases in your group by; however, you can put expressions in your group by.  In this case though it would look very ugly.  Something like:

```
select datename(weekday, calllog.RecvdDate) as Ticketday,
    <<BIG CASE STATEMENT HERE>> as CallTime, 
    count(distinct(CallTime)) as CallCount
from SERVER.xxxx.dbo.view_calllog calllog
where calllog.RecvdDate > '2015-01-01'
    and calllog.NameRecvdBy = 'IVR User Account'
    and calllog.CallDesc LIKE '%string%'
group by datename(weekday, calllog.RecvdDate), <<BIG CASE STATEMENT HERE>>
order by Ticketday, CallTime
```

Another way would be to use a subquery so you don't have to look at that big case statement twice. :)

```
select Ticketday, 
    CallTime, 
    count(distinct(CallTime)) as CallCount
from
    (
    select datename(weekday, calllog.RecvdDate) as Ticketday,
    CASE WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '00:00:00' and '01:00:00' THEN '00:00 to 01:00' 
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '01:00:00' and '02:00:00' THEN '01:00 to 02:00' 
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '02:00:00' and '03:00:00' THEN '02:00 to 03:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '03:00:00' and '04:00:00' THEN '03:00 to 04:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '04:00:00' and '05:00:00' THEN '04:00 to 05:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '05:00:00' and '06:00:00' THEN '05:00 to 06:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '06:00:00' and '07:00:00' THEN '06:00 to 07:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '07:00:00' and '08:00:00' THEN '07:00 to 08:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '08:00:00' and '09:00:00' THEN '08:00 to 09:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '09:00:00' and '10:00:00' THEN '09:00 to 10:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00' THEN '10:00 to 11:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '11:00:00' and '12:00:00' THEN '11:00 to 12:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '12:00:00' and '13:00:00' THEN '12:00 to 13:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '13:00:00' and '14:00:00' THEN '13:00 to 14:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '14:00:00' and '15:00:00' THEN '14:00 to 15:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '15:00:00' and '16:00:00' THEN '15:00 to 16:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '16:00:00' and '17:00:00' THEN '16:00 to 17:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '17:00:00' and '18:00:00' THEN '17:00 to 18:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '18:00:00' and '19:00:00' THEN '18:00 to 19:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '19:00:00' and '20:00:00' THEN '19:00 to 20:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '20:00:00' and '21:00:00' THEN '20:00 to 21:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '21:00:00' and '22:00:00' THEN '21:00 to 22:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '22:00:00' and '23:00:00' THEN '22:00 to 23:00'
        WHEN calllog.RecvdTime between '23:00:00' and '23:59:59' THEN '23:00 to 00:00'
        END as CallTime
    from SERVER.xxxx.dbo.view_calllog calllog
    where calllog.RecvdDate > '2015-01-01'
    and calllog.NameRecvdBy = 'IVR User Account'
    and calllog.CallDesc LIKE '%string%'
    ) CallData
group by Ticketday, CallTime
order by Ticketday, CallTime
```