# How to group by multiple columns using alias in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Grabbed a query from some old code and I'm trying to make it work. Every time I submit the query I get the error:

> Error code 207, SQL state S0001: Invalid column name 'Grade'

Code:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS PieceCount
    ,shifttimes.shiftid AS ShiftId
    ,specienames.NameText AS Specie
    ,gradenames.NameText AS Grade
    ,DryerNum
    ,CreatedLocal
FROM 
    sheets, shifttimes, Specienames, GradeNames
WHERE 
    sheets.ShiftIndex = shifttimes.ShiftIndex
    AND sheets.SpecieNameIndex = specienames.NameIndex
    AND sheets.gradenameindex = gradenames.NameIndex
    AND CreatedLocal >= '2015-04-01'
    AND CreatedLocal < '2015-06-01'
GROUP BY 
    ShiftId, Grade, DryerNum, Specie
```

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497241/how-do-i-perform-a-group-by-on-an-aliased-column-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: There's nothing whatsoever to do with Java here.  Tags edited.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the error i think you should change

```
GROUP BY ShiftId
    ,Grade
    ,DryerNum
    ,Specie
```

TO

```
GROUP BY shifttimes.shiftid
    ,gradenames.NameText
    ,DryerNum
    ,specienames.NameText
```

**NOTE:**

In your select you have `,CreatedLocal` but not in your `group by`, you have to remove it from the select or include on the `group by`

**SUGGESTION:**

Try to use Alias and Implicit joins (having two tables in the from clause) is a deprecated syntax, and it's recommended to switch to the modern, explicit, syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS PieceCount
    ,ST.shiftid AS ShiftId
    ,SN.NameText AS Specie
    ,GN.NameText AS Grade
    ,DryerNum    
FROM 
   sheets S
inner join shifttimes ST
   ON S.ShiftIndex = ST.ShiftIndex
inner join Specienames SN
   ON S.SpecieNameIndex = SN.NameIndex
inner join GradeNames GN
   ON S.gradenameindex = GN.NameIndex
WHERE 
    CreatedLocal >= '2015-04-01'
AND CreatedLocal < '2015-06-01'
GROUP BY 
     ST.shiftid
    ,GN.NameText
    ,DryerNum
    ,SN.NameText
```

Comment: Yes.  The `GROUP BY` clause cannot use column aliases defined in the `SELECT` list.  From a logic / process flow perspective, grouping happens before selection.  Also yes, the select list of an aggregate query must list only grouping columns and / or functions of the groups (though some DBs permit other columns as an extension).