# How to sum values from different rows in SQL that have the same argument in CASE-WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, case-when

Here is my code and this is my problem:

I have three diferente values for codCanal that I want to name as **Rota (02, 03 and 05)**. But when I run this query, I get three different rows for this value. Something like:

```
Ano | Mes | Canal | Volume
2015 | 01 | AS | 4423
2015 | 01 | Rota | 552
2015 | 01 | Rota | 744
2015 | 01 | Rota | 1223 
2015 | 01 | HSA | 6510
```

I want to show just 1 row with the sum of these values (552 + 744 + 1223). How can I solve this?

I tried to use `SUM(CASE WHEN)` but it returns a new column, and this is not what I want.

Thanks.

```
SELECT
    Vendas.datAno AS Ano,
    Vendas.datMes AS Mes,

    CASE WHEN Cliente.codCanal IN ('01') THEN 'AS'
    WHEN Cliente.codCanal IN ('02','03','05') THEN 'Rota'
    WHEN Cliente.codCanal IN ('08') THEN 'HSA'
    END AS Canal,

    ROUND(SUM(Vendas.vlrVolumeLiquido),0) AS Volume

FROM
    tblDadMetaRealCliente Vendas
    INNER JOIN
    tblCadOrganizacaoVenda OV
    ON Vendas.codOrganizacaoVenda = OV.codOrganizacaoVenda
    INNER JOIN
    tblCadCliente Cliente
    ON Vendas.codCliente = Cliente.codCliente
    INNER JOIN
    categoria_simulador_nova Catsim
    ON Vendas.codMaterial = Catsim.codMaterial

WHERE
    Catsim.Catsim IN ('CHESTER LANCHE') AND
    Vendas.datAno IN ('2014', '2015') AND
    Cliente.codCanal IN ('01', '02', '03', '05', '08')

GROUP BY
    Vendas.datAno,
    Vendas.datMes,
    Cliente.codCanal

ORDER BY
    Vendas.datAno,
    Vendas.datMes,
    Cliente.codCanal
```

Comment: Could you use SUM and WHERE in place of CASE - THEN?

Comment: Not sure if I got what you meant. I was trying to figure it out and the only way I found (didn't test though) is to use the result table of this query and create a new one using this SUM and WHERE. Would be this the best solution?

Comment: as a subquery taking the place of one of the fields SELECT SUM(*) WHERE Cliente.codCanal IN('02,'03',05').

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the converted column name in your `GROUP BY` clause, so that it will combine them into one group.

```
GROUP BY Vendas.datAno, Vendas.datMes, Canal
ORDER BY Vendas.datAno, Vendas.datMes, Canal
```

The above is for MySQL. In SQL-Server, you need to move the query into a subquery.

```
SELECT Ano, Mes, Canal, SUM(Volume) AS Volume
FROM (your query) AS subquery
GROUP BY datAno, datMes, Canal
```

Comment: Actually, if I try to use just Canal it returns an error. I used Cliente.codCanal instead).

Comment: The error is: _Mensagem 207, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 32
Invalid column name 'Canal'._

It seems that he can't find the new column name. Maybe doing a new query would work?

_SELECT Ano, Mes, Canal, SUM(Volume) FROM [result of this query] GROUP BY Ano, Mes, Canal_

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That doesn't look like a MySQL error message.

Comment: "Invalid column name" seems to be a SQL-Server error, not MySQL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497241/how-do-i-perform-a-group-by-on-an-aliased-column-in-ms-sql-server

Comment: Sorry dude. My mistake. It's not MySQL. Actually I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to extract data from a SQL Server. I didn't know that this would make any difference. I'm gonna read the link and try to solve this. Thanks man!!

Comment: Moving it into a subquery should work. That's shown in the second answer to that question.