# SQL - SUM Alias (GROUP BY)

Tags: sql-server

I'm having some issues grouping by an Alias column in SQL. This column contains both positive and negative numbers, and as a result, I want my "ARI_APLNO" column to be the sum of both the positive and negative numbers.

This is the code I currently have:

```
SELECT        ARI_APLNO, 
CASE 
WHEN ARI_TYPE = 1 OR ARI_TYPE = 3 THEN ARI_AMOUNT + ARI_SLSTAX 
WHEN ARI_TYPE = 2 AND ARI_AMOUNT < 0 THEN ARI_AMOUNT * - 1 
WHEN ARI_TYPE = 5 THEN (ARI_AMOUNT + ARI_SLSTAX) * - 1 
ELSE - ARI_AMOUNT END AS TotalValue
FROM            dbo.ARITEMA
GROUP BY TotalValue, ARI_APLNO
```

Wondering if I could please have some assistance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I perform a GROUP BY on an aliased column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497241/how-do-i-perform-a-group-by-on-an-aliased-column-in-sql-server)

Comment: You need to add your case statement in Group by then only it can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT        ARI_APLNO, 
CASE 
WHEN ARI_TYPE = 1 OR ARI_TYPE = 3 THEN ARI_AMOUNT + ARI_SLSTAX 
WHEN ARI_TYPE = 2 AND ARI_AMOUNT < 0 THEN ARI_AMOUNT * - 1 
WHEN ARI_TYPE = 5 THEN (ARI_AMOUNT + ARI_SLSTAX) * - 1 
ELSE - ARI_AMOUNT END AS TotalValue
FROM            dbo.ARITEMA
 )


SELECT ARI_APLNO,SUM(TotalValue) FROM CTE
GROUP BY ARI_APLNO
```

Try framing a CTE with all the conversions and then do SUM which will be easier and clean to handle new changes in future.